# LinkedList returning method

Tags: java, methods, return

Is it possible to create a method returning a LinkedList and what would be the correct syntax ?

```
public LinkedList  static void NewtonRaphson1() {
         return linkedlist;
}
```

Comment: The same syntax as if you would be returning any Object: `public static LinkedList<...> NewtonRaphson1`

Comment: Thank you, I lost 30 minutes just because I wrote LinkedList before static, I will remember this forever :)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

swap the `static` and the `return type` and remove the `void`:

```
public static LinkedList<String> NewtonRaphson1() {
    return new LinkedList<String>();
  }
```

you have defined a wrong syntax.

Edit: As Tunaki mentioned it is better to use generic and declare the type of data that is in your list:

```
LinkedList<String>
LinkedList<Integer>
LinkedList<Float>
LinkedList<MyObjectClass>
```

otherwise you get a warning from your IDE

> "LinkedList is a raw type. References to generic type LinkedList
>   should be parameterized"

the great benefit of that is:

> - Stronger type check during compile time
> - you dont need casting.

Comment: Thanks you! Works great.

Answer (score 0):

omit the "void", a void method return nothing ...

```
public static LinkedList NewtonRaphson1() {
     return linkedlist;
}
```